# Github Jekyll how to make real page format same as preview

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

My github jekyll structure looks like next:

[image]

after I enter `_posts` and create `.md` file, it looks like:

[image]

the corresponding code is:

````
 Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming. 
 The generics looks like:    
 ```Java    
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();    
 //add item to list    
 String s = list.get(0);   
 ```    
 or    
 ```Java   
 public class Box<T> {
        // T stands for "Type"
        private T t;
        //other code    
 }    
 ```
 The most commonly used type parameter names are:    
 ```    
 E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)    
 K - Key  

 ```
````

We can see that the format is nice, such as it has syntax highlight.

I called it **preview page**

However, when I enter into my page by typing my github page url to see, it likes:

[image]

I called it **real page**

We can see that **real page** looks bad, e.g. there is no syntax highlight, there are multiple borders for quoting code syntax etc.

Thus, how to make the **real page** format is the same as **preview page**?

Comment: Why are you using images? Please include code we can test with.

Comment: @antfuentes87 because the same code has different look so I use image to show difference. I added the my post source code, please check.

Comment: Any downvote with comment is appreciated such that I can improve my question. Just downvote make people confused.

Comment: The down-votes are due to the fact that you question doesn't have sense. But I think that it's not your fault if you don't know why it has no sense. Have a look at my question. I hope that it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you're relatively new to [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) so I have to do some clarification to you.

The result that you call "preview" is the result of your markdown parsed by GitHub. All markdowns have something in common so it's very likely that even if your parser is different almost all the things are parsed similarly. You could see a difference at the beginning of your "preview": the [yaml](http://yaml.org/) content is displayed as a table.

Let's come back to Jekyll. If you're using the default settings, the parser of your code is kramdown (you could change it in the `_config.yml` file). When you execute Jekyll, it builds your website. That means that it parses your markdown and convert it to HTML. How it converts to HTML depends on a lot of things based on your configuration and plugin installed.

By default, you have no highlight. If you want to change it, take a look at the [jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting). By default, it uses [Rogue](http://rouge.jneen.net/) but you can also use [Pigments](http://pygments.org/) or some other highlighter of your choice.

I don't think that this answer covers all your doubts and certainly not all your problems but it's to let you understand that your question, as it was posted, have not so much sense since your "preview page" and your "real page" are two completely distinct things. So google a bit, find what you want to achieve and ask a new question (you will surely have one in the near future).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.You are right, I am relatively new to Jekyll and your post let me understand my question. Actually I google a lot with keyword like "github jekyll page different format" and so on, but not result found. Maybe this is because I don't know how to describe the problem in english precisely(so I called them preview page and real page). So the preview page is result of my markdown parsed by Github, while the real page is the result of my markdown parsed by kramdown, right?

Comment: @frank Yes. To be more precise your "real page" could be the result of different parser that act one after the other (not only kramdown). It depends on what plugins you have in your jekill project.

Comment: Jekyll 3 and GitHub Pages now only support rouge for syntax highlighting, so in order to highlight the code, just place the code between \```java and \```, and the code is from https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers. Note, it should be \```java instead \```Java, even the latter can be parsed on github jekyll editor page, but it cannot be parsed when you type your website url.

Comment: @frank I don't know about GitHub pages, but accordly to [Jekyll template documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) rouge is the **default** highlighter. You could use other highlighters as well.

Comment: @frank Since Jekyll uses liquid, you could mark the content to be highlighted with `{% highlight <language> %}` and `{% endhighlight %}`.